# Python NameError: name 'methodA' is not defined for member method inside a class

Tags: python

My class is defined as the following:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    
    def methodA(self):
        print("methodA")

    def methodB(self):
        methodA()
        print("methodB")
```

And when I test it:

```
a = A(1)
a.methodB()
```

it returns the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-efe99826f05e> in <module>
     11 
     12 a = A(1)
---> 13 a.methodB()

<ipython-input-13-efe99826f05e> in methodB(self)
      7 
      8     def methodB(self):
----> 9         methodA()
     10         print("methodB")
     11 

NameError: name 'methodA' is not defined
```

I've checked different error reasons for this error, most of them are saying the called method(here is methodA()) is not defined before it's called by another method(methodB).
But I've already put methodA() above methodB().

Can any tell me what the matter is?

How can a class member method call another member method of the same class?

Really appreciate any hint!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`methodA` is indeed not defined. The method is accessible through the instance. You should call it like this:

```
def methodB(self):
    self.methodA()
    print("methodB")
```

The reason for this, very briefly, is that the class definition does not have its own scope once the class is defined. This is explained in detail in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) and [elsewhere](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/).

Comment: @BlueSea good question about the reason, I had to do some digging for the answer. The key word here is scope and the key question is, which scopes exist in method definitions. The answer seems to be that there is a local scope within `methodB` definition, and then there is the global module scope, and there is nothing in between where `methodA` would be present. I hope the links I added in the answer help you.

Answer (score -2):

Python assumes you're calling a global method, which has not been defined, hence the error. Calling it using the self. **class** attribute, instance methods can also access the class.

```
def methodB(self):
        self.methodA()
        print("methodB")
```